# dynamically add a widget on press of button

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I have created a class that has a widget that I want to appear on the home page as many times as the button is pressed.

https://gyazo.com/f9cc3e2c1f48e9efeb7b1d1c9b0b988e

as you can observe in this picture, the  'home care kit' rectangles is the widget, and I want them to appear when you press the add device button.

Here is the code of the button:

```
child: RaisedButton(

elevation: 0,
shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
  borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(40.0),
side: BorderSide(color: Colors.transparent)),
onPressed: () {print('Clicked!');},
color: Colors.transparent,
textColor: Colors.white,
child: Text('Add Device', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18)),

),
```

and the widget class is simply called HomeCareKit()

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append items dynamically to ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51343567/append-items-dynamically-to-listview)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first need a list of widgets:

```
List<Widget> _widgetList = [];
```

and you pass this list of widgets to your `ListView` or `Column` like:

```
ListView(
    children:_widgetList,
  )
```

to add a widget dynamically you can do this inside your `onPressed`:

```
setState(() {
  _widgetList.add(HomeCareKit());
});
```

Comment: amazing. Thank you so much it works!! I have been searching all day! One more thing. Do you know how i can refresh the screen when you click is so it instantly appears and so you dont have to go on another page and go back so it appears, like a refresh on click

Comment: @AndreiMarin make sure your page is `StatefulWidget`. the screen should automatically refresh with `setState`

Comment: Yeah, i forgot to add the setstate and i just added the widget add. Thank you so much again!

Comment: how to add an initial widget to that list.?